# wagtail + s3 + Heroku でウェブアプリ開発をすると画像アップロードでinternal error 500が出る。

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

こちらの質問は以下の質問の延長部分にあたります。
[元の質問](https://teratail.com/questions/353768)
またテラテイルでもマルチポストしています。(21/08/19)
[マルチポスト先](https://teratail.com/questions/355110)

###症状
画像をアップロードするとInternal server error 500が表示され、読み込まれなくなった。
また、ログにもエラーらしきものは見られない。

###開発環境

Django==3.2.6
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
wagtail==2.14
DB == postgres
server == Heroku stack-18

###コード

```
#base.py (開発・本番環境共通の設定部分にあたります。)

*以上、省略*

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'｛ AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ｝.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_URL = os.environ.get('AWS_URL')

STATICFILES_LOCATIONS = 'static'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = 'https://{ AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN }/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), '/Lib/site-packages/wagtail/admin/static/wagtailadmin'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://{ AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN }/images/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.MediaStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

```py
#backends.py

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATIONS

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'images'
    file_overwrite = False
```

以上二点が、重要と思われるコードです。
"images"となっている部分はもともと"media"としていたのですが、いくらそれでデプロイしてもmediaファイルなるものは生成されず、すでにあるimagesを指定しました。

###herokuのログ

```
2021-08-19T07:26:13.512552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/images/" host=DOMAIN request_id=db429860-ee9c-46cb-8c1d-a0276e6a871c fwd="134.180.192.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=218ms status=200 bytes=19658 protocol=https
2021-08-19T07:26:16.873790+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.167.33 - - [19/Aug/2021:07:26:16 +0000] "GET /admin/images/multiple/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20418 "https://DOMAIN/admin/images/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.73"
2021-08-19T07:26:16.875044+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/images/multiple/add/" host=DOMAIN request_id=d294a92c-ba2a-4419-a623-5bc726e68a33 fwd="134.180.192.60" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=114ms status=200 bytes=20971 protocol=https
2021-08-19T07:26:24.390868+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.167.33 - - [19/Aug/2021:07:26:24 +0000] "POST /admin/images/multiple/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 363 "https://DOMAIN/admin/images/multiple/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.73"
2021-08-19T07:26:24.391146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admin/images/multiple/add/" host=DOMAIN request_id=95e79995-3973-4aae-9584-9ad3432a1d41 fwd="134.180.192.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3610ms status=500 bytes=636 protocol=https
```

以上のコードにより先述の質問のcss問題は全て解決されました。
しかし、画像読み込みだけがいまだうまくいきません。みなさまのお力をお貸しいただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 前回の質問時とログインIDが異なっているようです。ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。参考: [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) / "元の質問" のリンク先が teratail になっていたり、Markdown も (こちらのサイトでは) 正しくないものになっています。同時に複数サイトで投稿する事を禁止しているわけではありませんが、単なるコピペで済ませずに各サイトにあった対応を心がけてみてください。

Comment: 「画像をアップロードするとInternal server error 500が出る」ということは、画像をアップロード（書き込み）しようとしているのですよね。
それと「画像読み込みだけがいまだうまくいきません」とは、どう関係しますか？

もし、画像のアップロードが出来ない（サーバには、画像が無い）という状況なら、読み込みができなくて当然（そもそも、画像が無いのだから）という気もします。
サーバのログを確認してみては、如何でしょうか。